# Docker Desktop Engine just stops as soon as we try to start it up ( [FAIL] DD0029: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt? )

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- .NET 6
- Windows 11 Enterprise
- Docker version  4.23.0 (120376).

When I run docker desktop on my computer, I get the following nondescript screen:

[image]

In order to get a diagnose this problem, I ran Windows Powershell in Administrator mode, and I ran the following:

> PS C:\Program Files\Docker\docker\resources> .\com.docker.diagnose.exe
>
> check Starting diagnostics
>
> [PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
>
> [PASS] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
>
> [SKIP] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
>
> [SKIP] DD0018: does the host support virtualization?
>
> [PASS] DD0001: is the application running?
>
> [SKIP] DD0022: is the Virtual Machine Platform Windows Feature
> enabled?
>
> [SKIP] DD0021: is the WSL 2 Windows Feature enabled?
>
> [PASS] DD0024: is WSL installed?
>
> [PASS] DD0025: are WSL distros installed?
>
> [PASS] DD0026: is the WSL LxssManager service running?
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:789: Failed to translate
>
> C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\Docker
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program  Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\system32
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\system32
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn<3>WSL (52)
> ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Scripts
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\TerraformCLI\terraform_1.5.7_windows_amd64
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Scripts\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> <3>WSL (52) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac.dotnet\tools
>
> Failed to mount C:, see dmesg for more details.
>
> **[FAIL] DD0029: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt? [    5.179460]
> EXT4-fs error (device sdc): ext4_put_super:1188: comm Interop:
> Couldn't clean up the journal**
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:789: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Roaming\Docker
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\system32
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\system32
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Scripts
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\TerraformCLI\terraform_1.5.7_windows_amd64
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Scripts\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> <3>WSL (55) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate
> C:\Users\ecyriac.dotnet\tools
>
> **Failed to mount C:, see dmesg for more details.**
>
> [PASS] DD0035: is the VM time synchronized?
>
> **[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? prereq failed: is the WSL 2 Linux
> filesystem corrupt?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running? prereq failed: can a VM be
> started?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? prereq failed: is
> the LinuxKit VM running?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? prereq failed: are the
> LinuxKit services running?**
>
> [PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
>
> **[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? prereq failed: is the Docker
> engine running?**
>
> [PASS] DD0013: is the $PATH ok?
>
> **[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? prereq failed: is the Docker
> engine running?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0005: is the user in the docker-users group? prereq failed:
> is the LinuxKit VM running?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0038: is the connection to Docker working? prereq failed: is
> the Docker engine running?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0014: are the backend processes running? prereq failed: is
> the LinuxKit VM running?**
>
> **[FAIL] DD0007: is the backend responding? prereq failed: are the
> backend processes running?**

As soon as I try to start Docker Desktop, it immediately stops. When I run the "com.docker.diagnose.exe check" , one of the failure messages states the following:

WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt

How can I go about correcting this problem?